# AngularJS: Move a div inside a placeholder div

Tags: css, angularjs

I have the following html:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
<div id="div5"></div>
<div id="div6"></div>
```

The output would be displayed as:

```
Div 1      Div 2
Div 3      Div 4
Div 5      Div 6
```

Given some information on page load Div 1 or Div 2 may be hidden.  If Div 1 is hidden I want to move Div 2 to the placeholder for Div 1 and move Div 5 to the placeholder for Div 2.  I always want Div 3 and Div 4 on the same line.  Currently if I hide a div the next one moves up in its place causing Div 3 and Div 4 to be on two different lines.  I have researched AngularJS and can't find a way to do this?  Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

```
<div id="placeholder1"></div>    <div id="placeholder2"></div>
<div id="placeholder3"></div>    <div id="placeholder4"></div>
<div id="placeholder5"></div>    <div id="placeholder6"></div>

<div id="memid">Member ID</div>    <div id="otherid">Other ID</div>
<div id="fName">First Name</div>    <div id="lName">Last Name</div>
<div id="dob">DOB</div>    <div id="otherInfo">Other Info</div>
```

Given the site the member id or other id may be hidden and I would like to move DOB to placeholder2 and OtherID to placeholder1 or leave member id in placeholder1 while keeping first and last name on the same row.  I am also using bootstrap grid for the layout.

Comment: if you want to force 3 and 4 together, then you will likely need to wrap an additional div around them.  something like http://plnkr.co/edit/H0BoEhoYVYk5vGTT8XGK?p=preview.  however, there isn't a way to move 5 to above 3 without doing some unusual tricks, depending on how this group of divs is generated;  you *might* be able to use a custom order filter if these are generated by `ng-repeat`, for example....

Comment: ultimately, you haven't really given enough information, and divs with numbers isn't really reflective of an actual use case which gives what you are trying to accomplish any context.....

Comment: An example would be something like:

     `<div id="div1">Member ID</div>     <div id="div2">Other ID</div>`
     `<div id="div3">First Name</div>     <div id="div4">Last Name</div>`
     `<div id="div5">DOB</div>     <div id="div6">Other Info</div>`

Given the site there may or may not be a need to show Member ID or Other ID and I want to move DOB up into the empty slot on the top row if one is hidden.

Comment: It's actually an aesthetic thing at this point.

Comment: so there are a few ways that you can make your layout respond the way you are describing, but a lot depends on how the layout is generated.  is it static HTML or are you using `ng-repeat` to iterate through properties, or some other way of outputting your fields?

Comment: It is static HTML and the ng-show or data-ng-hide is used to show or hide the div containers.  I am working on adding placeholder divs now actually.  I will update the original post.

Comment: your update makes less sense now than before.  What code are you using to "move" these divs into the placeholders?  That doesn't seem like a standard angular technique for managing the DOM....

Comment: I'm trying to write the code to move the docs into the placeholders. There currently is no code to do it. I'm wanting to move divs around based on which id is hidden on the first line. I want to move the DOB div up to div2 if one of the id divs are hidden. If they are both visible then I will leave them alone and the DOB div stays put.

Comment: right, but that's my point;  moving DIVs and using placeholders isn't the angular way.  the angular way would be to dynamically write a template based on the condition.  you are approaching the problem the wrong way if you were expecting angular to move the DOM around the way a framework like jQuery might.

Comment: Ok I'll take your direction and see what I can come up with. Appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1):

i dont understand, where is needed angular. The problem could be solved only with css:

```
div{
float:left;
width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is likely going to be to use javascript to handle this.  You can do this without Angular, though.  You could manually move the elements around within the set of nodes containing the six divs.  You could also try taking the html content from one div and moving it to another.

```
if (/*condition that hides div1*/){
    Div1.html(Div2.html());
    Div2.html(Div5.html());
    Div5.hide();
}
```

You could also try applying css classes that manually place the elements on the page.

Comment: only issue I have is I need to implement the move inside the contoller.  I'm fairly new to angular also.

Comment: If you're implementing the change on the controller side, the general ideas I suggested would still work.  Either set each child in a particular order within the parent, apply the html content to a different div (in the order you want them to appear), or use css to place them where you want them to be.  I'm not familiar enough with server-side Angular to tell you the exact syntax for doing those things.